# issue with a firebase query

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am using react native firebase firestore Lib , I want to insert data to a collection once inserted and based on the new firebase id I have to create a new child document .
so I have tried my code :

```
const geocollection=GeoFirestore.collection("testcol");

           try{
             await geocollection.add({
                title: title,
                 timestamps: firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                 price1 : price1,
                 coordinates : new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(40.7589, -73.9851),
                 images:  firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(...downloadUrls),
      
             }) 
             .then(async (e)=> 
                 {
                  if(menu1title !== null && menu1title !== 'undefined'){
                    await doc(e.id).
                    add({
                      menu1title : menu1title,
                      price1 : price1,
                      image : image1
                    }) 
                  }
                 }
             
             ,setInsertionSucced(true), setInsertionFailed(false))
          
           } catch{
            setInsertionFailed(true)
            setButtonClicked(false)
            setInsertionSucced(false)
           } 

 could you help to  get this done , I don't get errors  but no insertion can be made
```

Answer (score 1):

`add` returns a docReference and not a document itself. You will need to fetch that document after adding it. Trying to read fields on the docReference based on your inserted value will return `undefined`.

https://rnfirebase.io/reference/firestore/collectionreference#add